# Freeze rows in a Macro to stop Hide/ Unhide moving when rows are added above in excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I have very basic knowledge! I have a tick box which when ticked unhides certain rows. Is there a way of freezing the rows in the code so that if a row is inserted or deleted above in the excel shett the macro recognizes the movement in row numbers? In an excel formula I would use $

```
   'hide or unhide Row:
Sheet1.Rows("123:115").Hidden = Not (CheckBox1.Value)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have anything in the row to identify it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean ?

Comment: Well what distinguishes row 123? Do you have a bit of text or numbers in there? Then you could base the code on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a range name e.g. MyRows equal to 115:123 (entire rows).

In your code:

```
 [MyRows].EntireRow.Hidden = True  #Hide rows
 [MyRows].EntireRow.Hidden = False #UnHide rows
```

It is impervious to insert/delete rows as long as you don't select a row in the range when you do the insert/delete.

HTH